# Dynamically selected element not being selected

Tags: c#, dynamic, drop-down-menu, selenium-webdriver, element

Any ideas on why this code snippet is not selecting thee clicked element. I am dynamically selecting elements using the code, which it does well but when it comes to selecting the clicked element it doesn't. What could be wrong? please help.

```
IList<IWebElement> DynamicDatasource = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@id='s2id_Parameters_0_Validation_TheFormat']//span[starts-with(@id, 'select2-chosen-')]"));
if (DynamicDatasource.Count > 0)
{
    File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\ken4ward\Desktop\Tidy\WriteLines.txt", DynamicDatasource.Count.ToString());
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    actions.MoveToElement(DynamicDatasource[0]).Click().SendKeys("Real Integer").Build().Perform();
    IList<IWebElement> standard = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@class='select2-drop select2-display-none select2-with-searchbox select2-drop-active']//ul[starts-with(@id, 'select2-results-')]"));
    if (standard.Count > 0)
    {
        File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\ken4ward\Desktop\Tidy\Writing.txt", DynamicDatasource.Count.ToString());
        actions.MoveToElement(standard[0]).Click().Build().Perform();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to match **all** of those class names? I'd guess `select2-with-searchbox` was meaningful, but `select2-display-none` and `select2-drop-active` are not.

Comment: The test steps executed fine until it got to executing this line of code: ```actions.MoveToElement(standard[0]).Click().Build().Perform();``` I'm very sure it's only an index of zero that it should click since it'll be the element at the top.

Comment: If it was me I'd want to log the whole of `standard` *just in case* something unexpected was at [0]. Though why are you moving and clicking with the Actions API not thru IWebElement? Maybe try the latter just in case the move-to is problematic.

Comment: Thanks, @Andrew, finally got it working by this cute suggestion. I have to print out the text at the index and confirmed that it was actually seeing nothing at index "0", so incremented it to 2, at this point, it was able to print and click. ```actions.MoveToElement(standard[2]).Click().Build().Perform();```

Comment: Great, glad it's working.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know the class you are is a compound class. Locating compound class may not work properly. Instead try Cssselector.

```
IList<IWebElement> standard = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@class='select2-drop select2-display-none select2-with-searchbox select2-drop-active']//ul[starts-with(@id, 'select2-results-')]"));
```

So Try the below hope it should work

```
IList<IWebElement> standard = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".select2-drop.select2-display-none.select2-with-searchbox.select2-drop-active"));
```

Comment: Thanks. Still performs the same way